# C variable arguments in unsigned char?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I read this page to know how to use variable arguments:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm

All right, integer result is ok.
But when I replace its type to `unsigned char`, everything goes wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double average(int num,...) {

   va_list valist;
   double sum = 0.0;
   int i;

   /* initialize valist for num number of arguments */
   va_start(valist, num);

   /* access all the arguments assigned to valist */
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      sum += va_arg(valist, int);
   }

   /* clean memory reserved for valist */
   va_end(valist);

   return sum/num;
}

void foo(unsigned char arg_count,int num,...) {

   va_list valist;
   int i;

   /* initialize valist for num number of arguments */
   va_start(valist, num);

   /* access all the arguments assigned to valist */
   for (i = 0; i < arg_count; i++) {
      printf("%02x,",va_arg(valist, int));
   }

   /* clean memory reserved for valist */
   va_end(valist);
}

void bar(int num,...) {

   va_list valist;
   int i;

   /* initialize valist for num number of arguments */
   va_start(valist, num);

   /* access all the arguments assigned to valist */
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      printf("%02x,",va_arg(valist, int));
   }

   /* clean memory reserved for valist */
   va_end(valist);
}

int main() {
   printf("Average of 2, 3, 4, 5 = %f\n", average(4, 2,3,4,5));
   printf("Average of 5, 10, 15 = %f\n", average(3, 5,10,15));
   foo(3,'a','b','c');
   printf("\n");
   bar('a','b','c');
}
```

Result as following:

```
Compiling the source code....
$gcc main.c -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
Average of 2, 3, 4, 5 = 3.500000
Average of 5, 10, 15 = 10.000000
62,63,400aab,
62,63,00,0a,c0a4700,4009e0,b0ef50a,01,64f5ead8,40000,400934,00,440c7120,400540,64f5ead0,00,00,83cc7120,be487120,00,00,00,bea8d73,be96d10,b6b9950,00,00,00,400540,64f5ead0,40056a,64f5eac8,c0c0180,01,64f5f3d3,00,64f5f3d8,64f5f473,64f5f48d,64f5f4a9,64f5f4b2,64f5f4c8,64f5f4e5,64f5f50d,64f5f796,64f5f7af,64f5f7d9,64f5f7f8,64f5f802,64f5f80a,64f5f823,64f5f83b,64f5f850,64f5f876,64f5f87e,64f5f898,64f5f8d0,64f5f8db,64f5f8e3,64f5f946,64f5f972,64f5f998,64f5fa2d,64f5fa63,64f5fa79,64f5ff2f,64f5ffc9,00,21,64fdb000,10,bfebfbff,06,1000,11,64,03,400040,04,38,05,09,07,be98000,08,00,09,400540,0b,30,0c,30,0d,30,0e,30,17,
```

Everything was the same with the `int` version, but why result is different?

Comment: _"when I replace its type"_ What's type? Where?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood. Your comment *"initialize valist for num number of arguments"* is wrong. Statement `va_start(valist, num);` only uses `num` for locating first variable argument, it does not use it's numeric value until it's used in `for` loop.

Comment: That particular tutorial is worded in a misleading way. Find you a different one. In particular, "the one just before the ellipses is always an int" is strongly misleading. It doesn't have to be an `int` and it doesn't have to represent the total number of variable arguments passed. It hust happens that this particular function chooses to use these *conventions*. There are nothing in the language that forces them or creates you a varargs count out of thin air.

Comment: Ok, guys, I know the `num` isn't the count of variable arguments.
But return to the topic, how should I access every arguments?

Comment: @naive231: I don't understand your question. What is it that you are trying to do? Just print all the arguments? You need some way to tell the varargs function how many arguments you have. Two ways of doing it is by sending the number as the first argument, or by having a special value that marks the end of the argument list. There is no built-in mechanism for getting the number of arguments. Was that the question?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: The question is, no matter I run `foo()` or `bar()`, it prints `62,63,...`(they are hexadecimals), but my first argument is `'a'`, it should be `61`, not `62`. The argument counts may be solved, but the content is just wrong, where is my first argument ?

Comment: @naive231: Remember that `va_start(valist, num)` initializes `valist` to start with the argument _after_ `num`. Both functions are called with `'a'` in the position of `num`, so the first value from `va_arg` will be `'b'`, which is 98 decimal, or 62 hexadecimal.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: No, `foo(3,'a','b','c')` is called with first argument `3`, so *first* argument should be `'a'`, right?

Comment: @naive231: I think you forget that `foo` has two normal, non-variadic parameters: `arg_count` and `num`. `3` goes into `arg_count`, `'a'` goes into `num` (which is not used in the function), and `'b'` is the first of the variadic arguments, so it will be the first value from `va_arg`.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Oh! I got it. Finally I change implementation of `bar()` as follows:

void bar(int num,...) {

   va_list valist;
   int i;

   /* initialize valist for num number of arguments */
   va_start(valist, num);

   /* access all the arguments assigned to valist */
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      printf("%02x,",va_arg(valist, int));
   }

   /* clean memory reserved for valist */
   va_end(valist);
}

and then call `bar(0,'a','b','c');`. Finally it shows the `61,62,63` as I expected.

Thanks @ThomasPadron-McCarthy! You really help !

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I don't understand what it is that you are trying to do with your code, but aren't you just sending `'a'`, which typically will be the character code 97, as the number of arguments to the function `bar`? So it tries to print 97 arguments.

`va_start(valist, num)` initializes `valist` to start with the argument *after* `num`. In both function calls, to `foo` and `bar`, `'a'` is in the position of `num`, so the first value from `va_arg` will be `'b'`, which is 98 decimal, or 62 hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
va_start(valist, num);
```

with

```
va_start(valist, arg_count);
```

in `foo` and change its prototype to:

```
void foo(unsigned char arg_count, ...)
```

You're declaring 3 arguments but starting the va_list 2 from the end.

Also, change this

```
bar('a','b','c');
```

to:

```
bar(3, 'a','b','c');
```

in `main`.  You have omitted the `num` argument.